# Get content from the parent page

Tags: javascript, parent-child

When you click on print note, I am expecting another window to pop-up with the notes you took. In my case, it keeps showing up blank.

Please let me know if I should provide more details:

Page(1) with the text area

```
<textarea id="sermon_notes" cols="5" rows="5"></textarea>
<a href="../notes/print/forgiveness/index.html" target="_blank" class="btn_small_cmg">     <span>Print Notes</span></a>
```

Page(2) with javascript trying to pull the information you wrote on page(1) so it can show up on page(2)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Media | New Foundation Christian Ministries </title>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/popout.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/print.css" media="print" type="text/css" />

    </head>

    <body class="about">
      <div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">
    <a href="javaScript:window.print();" class="print"><span>Print</span></a>
    <h1><img src="../images/logo.png" alt="New Foundation Christian Ministries" />       </h1>
</div>
<div class="content">
        <div class="page_header">
        <h2>Notes</h2>
    </div>
    <h1></h1>
        <h1>some text</h1>
        <small>ate</small>

        <br/><br/><br/>


            <h3>My Notes:</h3>
            <p>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                // Get the notes from the parent page
                var message_notes = window.opener.document.getElementById('sermon_notes').value;
                // Replace out the new line character with a <br>
                message_notes = message_notes.replace(new RegExp( "\\n", "g" ),"<br />");
                document.write(message_notes);
            </script>
            </p> 

</div>
<div class="footer">

   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery? Is the index.html you are calling blank?

Comment: You're not really opening a new window, but a `_blank`, which is not the same.

Comment: this is exactly what i am trying to do, there's don't seem to work neither. http://fellowshipdallas.org/media/player/media/what-we-should-know-about-the-end-times/video/

Comment: Try using `window.open()`

Comment: I would use a form and send the info through POST

Comment: tried window.open didn't work.

Comment: What about it didn't work? The window didn't open or you still get a blank page?

Comment: still get a blank page.

Comment: No errors? Do you have some more code.. show us how you are opening the window.

Comment: the opening of the window, works just fine with the code I posted previously, the problem is to actually getElementById.

Comment: I have update the code to show more details hope that help, and thank you so much for trying to help.

Comment: `window.opener` in the new window will probably be undefined since you didn't call `window.open()` in the page where you are opening the new window. Therefore your page is blank probably.

Comment: I have tried at least I think I have, Can you gave an example of what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, my above code work just fine, is the fact my link did not contain the http but rather files. it would not work unless you have http, so it wont work on your local server.

Thank you all for helping.